# ASP.NET MVC3 Metadata problem on class named as .NET keyword

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, metadata

I've a problem when adding metadata to a class named as a reserved keyword. During the generation of the data model (the DBML file), an @ has been added to the class name to have it working.

When I apply metadata to the class, it is not working (metadata info is not taken in consideration - the DisplayName and other validation stuff). For all other classes of my project (that do not have a class name as a reserved keyword, it is working). It is currently not possible to rename that class.

Generated class definition:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.operators")]
public partial class @operator : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{...}
```

MetaData class definition:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(OperatorMetaData))]
public partial class @operator
{
}

public class OperatorMetaData
{
    [DisplayName("Operator Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Operator type is required.")]
    public int operator_type_id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Anyone any idea how to work around this? Or what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Just change the case of operators table to Operators and use CamelCase in your code.

Comment: in the dbml table definition file ?

Comment: @zihotki: this is working to avoid having the @operator in the code, but it didn't solve my problem! I finally found the cause of the problem. Excuse me because I forgot to mention something: the generated class definition was in the 'Models' namespace, while my metadata definition was in 'Models.MetaData' namespace. When putting all in the same namespace it's working (even with the @operator notation). Anyway, thanks for the help!